# Waiting for time limit or user input in Java for Snake Game

Tags: java

I'm trying to reconstruct the classic Snake game in Java but can't seem to get the user input right. I want the system to wait a set amount of time, or until the user hits a WASD key (whichever is first) then move on with the code. I saw in another answer on here to use BufferedReader and bf.ready() as a possible solution, but for some reason that doesn't work.

Here's the code I'm currently using. Currently it always prints input out as test, which means it thinks the user never typed anything in. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
        double x = .75; // wait x seconds at most
        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(r);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < x * 1000
                && !in.ready()) {
        }
        Direction d = Direction.up;
        String input = "test";
        if (in.ready()) {
            input = in.readLine().toLowerCase();
            if (input.equals("a")) {
                d = Direction.left;
            } else if (input.equals("s")) {
                d = Direction.down;
            } else if (input.equals("d")) {
                d = Direction.right;
            }
        } else {
            d = snake.getDirection();
        }
        System.out.println(input);
        in.close();
        r.close();
        return d;
```

Comment: The use of a buffered reader and "readLine" means that you would have to press a<enter> to get input into the program.  Is this a terminal program?  Or does it use some GUI framework?  If it is a console program, you might try operating directly on System.in, eg System.in.available() and System.in.read()